# Determining how many elements in a matrix are equal or bigger compared to another matrix element-wise

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's say:

```
a = 1 2 3
    4 5 6
    7 8 9

b = 3 2 1
    6 5 4
    9 8 7
```

So in MATLAB: `a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]; b = [3 2 1; 6 5 4; 9 8 7];`.  I want to know how many elements in `a` are equal or bigger than the element in the same place in `b`.   So in this example, the result will be 6.

Comment: It will be 6 elements, not 3.

Answer (score 2):

Let

```
a = [1 2 3
     4 5 6
     7 8 9];
b = [3 2 1
     6 5 4
     9 8 7];
```

then the expression

```
c = a>=b;
```

gives you the positions of the elements where a is larger than b.

```
sum(c(:));
```

Gives you the number of such elements.

Comment: In one line, you could unroll both matrices into vectors, then do the comparison and sum simultaneously: `c = sum(a(:) >= b(:));`